# meetup rate limit only 200, problems with getting other records

Tags: r, jsonlite, meetup

I am trying to get events for a meetup. The problem is I am only getting around 200 events. So, I tried doing an offset and specifying the pagination as specified in other stackoverflow question but is not working. It is giving me the same records each time. Can anyone advise on how to get other records? Thanks so much. Below is the R code.

```
 library(jsonlite)
 data1<- data.frame(fromJSON("https://api.meetup.com/bostonphp/events?key=yourkey&status=past&page=40&offset=7", flatten = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure that I wrote the package `meetupapi` that I reference in my answer.

#### installation

Currently the development version on github is recommended because I've yet to submit some bug fixes to CRAN.

```
devtools::install_github("zacdav/meetupapi")
```

#### Get meetup events

```
library(meetupapi)
api_key = "************API_KEY_HERE***************"
boston_events <- get_meetup_events("bostonphp", api_key)
```